# How to capture pygame screen?

Tags: python, video-capture, pygame

How can I capture and save a sequence of images or a video of a pygame screen? 
Basically I want to share my game video on youtube. Also, want to make a tutorial.

The game is rendered mainly in a loop:

```
def main():
    while True:
        GetInput()
        Move()
        Shift()
        Draw()
```

With the `Draw()` function doing all the `blit()` and stuff before doing the `pygame.display.flip()`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `pygame.image.save` on your screen surface:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode(...)

...

pygame.image.save(window, "screenshot.jpeg")
```

Note that this will slow down your program tremendously. If it is time-based, you may wish to fake the framerate when doing a capture.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer said you could save the current screen with the `pygame.image.save` method

This is a good idea, however you might not want to save the images on the hard drive while the game is running, also pointed out by the question. Instead, you should save the screens in the program and then process them after the game has stopped running.

Here is my code with comments, that only shows the general idea of how a screen recording might work. It uses opencv (with numpy) and pygame but you have to install ffmpeg to convert the images to a video (try `ffmpg` in the terminal to test). Don't let the program run too long, because the saving still takes quite a while and is about proportional to the recorded frames. For more efficiency, you could only record every second frame or so.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg
from pygame import surfarray

def pg_to_cv2(cvarray:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
    cvarray = cvarray.swapaxes(0,1) #rotate
    cvarray = cv2.cvtColor(cvarray, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) #RGB to BGR
    return cvarray

def timer_wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        #print("Finished:" ,func.__name__ ,end-start)
        return end - start
    return inner

@contextmanager
def video_writer(*args,**kwargs):
    video = cv2.VideoWriter(*args,**kwargs)
    try:
        yield video
    finally:
        video.release()

@timer_wrapper
def save_frames(frames: list, average_dt: float|list, file_type: str = "mp4", name: str = "screen_recording"):
    if type(average_dt) is list: average_dt = sum(average_dt)/len(average_dt) # force average_dt to be a float
    size = frames[0].get_size()
    codec_dict={
        "avi":'DIVX',
        "mp4":'MP4V'
    }
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec_dict[file_type])
    with video_writer(name+"."+file_type, codec, 1000/average_dt, size) as video: # file_name, codec, average_fps, dimensions
        for frame in frames:
            try:
                pg_frame = surfarray.pixels3d(frame) # convert the surface to a np array. Only works with depth 24 or 32, not less
            except:
                pg_frame = surfarray.array3d(frame) # convert the surface to a np array. Works with any depth
            cv_frame = pg_to_cv2(pg_frame)  # then convert the np array so it is compatible with opencv
            video.write(cv_frame)   #write the frame to the video using opencv

def draw_fps(s:pg.Surface,clock:time.Clock): 
    fps = clock.get_fps()
    sysfont.render_to(s,(100,100),str(fps),fgcolor=nice_green)

# initializing globals (colors, fonts, window, etc.)
pg.init()
sysfont = pg.freetype.SysFont(None,40)
BLACK = (0,)*3
nice_green = pg.Color("chartreuse2")
size=(1000, 600)
pg.display.set_caption("Screen Recording")
window = pg.display.set_mode(size)
# this is to save the frames
frames = []
dts = []
clock = pg.time.Clock()

running=True
try:
    while running:
        dt = clock.tick(60) # aim for ... fps
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running=False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    running=False
        window.fill(BLACK)
        draw_fps(window,clock)
        window_copy = window.copy() # if we don't copy the window then we will have the same image in all frames at the end
        frames.append(window_copy) # We save the current frame together with the time passed between the frames
        dts.append(dt)
        pg.display.flip()
        #if len(frames) >= 100: running = False # uncomment this to stop the game after ... frames for similar results in every run"
finally:
    pg.quit()
    # At this stage, the game ended and the cleanup process can start. For this we convert the frames to opencv images
    # Only then we will write the video to the hard drive (That is what makes the save so slow).
    # General information about the recording
    frame_num = len(frames)
    dt_sum = sum(dts)
    average_dt = dt_sum/frame_num
    # This is only an approximation: 
    # for each frame we have width * height many pixels -> frame_num * width * height
    # A Surface needs get_bytesize() many bytes per pixel (In this case 4 bytes, because we set the depth of the display to 32 bits)
    memory_usage_approx = frame_num * size[0] * size[1] * frames[0].get_bytesize()  #https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_bytesize
    print("Total time:" , dt_sum/1000,"s")
    print("Average time per frame:" , average_dt,"ms")
    print("Number of frames:", frame_num)
    print("Memory usage approximation" , memory_usage_approx/1000, "KB")
    args = (frames,dts,"avi","screen_recording")
    time_for_save = save_frames(*args)
    file_name = args[3]+"."+args[2]
    video_memory_usage = os.path.getsize(file_name)
    print("Video memory usage:" , video_memory_usage/1000, "KB")
    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        print("Total time:" , dt_sum/1000,"s\nNumber of frames:", frame_num,"\nSize:",size,"\nTime for save:",time_for_save,"s\nSaved in file:",file_name,file=f)
        print("_"*100,file=f)
```

Or you just use a lib like [Pygame Recorder](https://github.com/tdrmk/pygame_recorder).

Answer (score 1):

```
x3 = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(screen)
x3 = x3[:,:,::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a cool way;
you can use

```py
x3 = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(window)
```

to get all the pixels on any surface or the screen (the window variable)!
You can use this in things like NumPy where you can use the code

```py
array = numpy.uint8(x3)
```

to get the image of the surface as a NumPy array and then

```py
im = PIL.Image.fromarray(array)
```

to make it a Pillow image, if you want. Then you can show it with a simple `im.show()` or just do whatever with it.