# How to take screenshot of entire display pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, screenshot, screen-capture

I am creating a painter software and want the user to be able to save their image after they have finished creating it, so I tried `pygame.image.save(pygame.display.get_surface(), "/home/user/screenshot.png")`. I made a quick drawing and pressed the key I set which would save the image. I look at the image, and it's only saved the blank display surface, not the `pygame.draw.rect()`s of the actual drawing. I looked at the following links: [How to capture pygame screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087484/how-to-capture-pygame-screen) https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118372/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-certain-part-of-the-screen-in-pygame [Can python get the screen shot of a specific window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809729/can-python-get-the-screen-shot-of-a-specific-window) and much more. How would I take a screenshot of the entire display screen along with the drawing? This is my mainloop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    updateWindow() # Updates window
    clearWindow() # Clears window
    checkEvents() # Checks events
    redrawItems() # Redraws your drawing
    pygame.event.pump()
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: duplicate question: [how to take screenshot of entire display pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342477/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-display-pygame?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C0.0000)

Comment: That is literally this question, Yax P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pygame.Surface.copy` on the display surface. See docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy).

So if `display` is your screen, then:

```py
screencopy = display.copy()
```

should get you a copy of the display image in `screencopy`. Remember because of double buffering it will give you a copy of what you would see on the screen if you did an `display.update()` right then, which might be different that what is showing on the screen if you have done things  that have not yet been pushed to the screen yet by an `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using pygame.image.save(Surface, filename), which you can read more about
[here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save)

Below is a simple function that will save a portion of the display as an image.

```
def Capture(display,name,pos,size): # (pygame Surface, String, tuple, tuple)
    image = pygame.Surface(size)  # Create image surface
    image.blit(display,(0,0),(pos,size))  # Blit portion of the display to the image
    pygame.image.save(image,name)  # Save the image to the disk**
```

What this function does is created a pygame surface named image. Then the area (pos,size) is blitted to image at its origin. Finally, pygame.image.save(Surface, filename) will be called and save image to the disk.

For example, if we want to save a 100x100 image named "Capture.png" at the pos 50x50 on the display, name would equal "Capture.png", pos would equal (50,50), and size would equal (100,100), and the function call would look as such:

```
Capture(display,"Capture.png",(50,50),(100,100))
```